# Finding small circles in a image using Opencv c++

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Below is the attached image and i am trying to detect **small circles** present inside the big circle and get it's **x and y coordinate**.
so far i have tried using  **HoughCircles**, **findContours** but i can't get the desired result.

can anyone suggest how to solve this particular problem.

[image]

**Edited:**
I have used this algorithm

```
    cv::Mat tmp_mat, grey_mat;
    cv::cvtColor(load_image, tmp_mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::GaussianBlur(tmp_mat,grey_mat,cv::Size(7,7),0,0);
    cv::imshow("color", grey_mat);

    // Step -2
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i > hierarchy;

    cv::Mat edged;
    cv::Canny(grey_mat, edged, 20,140);
    cv::findContours(edged, contours, hierarchy,cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    std::cout << "Contour Size: " << contours.size();
```

after doing canny edge detection i get this image
[image]

although the code is detecting the circles inside the big circle. The problem is how to exclued the circles outside the big circle.

Comment: I would suggest first threshold the image. Then try applying morphology open then close with small circular kernel to remove small ones. If the morphology does not work well, then get contours and filter on area or perimeter. You can get the centroids of the contours for the coordinates. Or you can do Hough circles and get the center of the circles.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Corner Harris detector](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d7d/tutorial_harris_detector.html). It will detect corners in the image, which the small circles are. However, it will probably detect more than one corner for each circle, so you can try to do some filtering on the result.

There is an online demo you can try right away: [demo](https://fiveko.com/tutorials/image-processing/feature-points-using-harris-corner-detector/)